# Migrating Umbraco 4.7.1 from IIS6 to IIS7

Tags: iis, migration, iis-7.5, umbraco

I have taken over an Umbraco (version 4.7.1) installation from a previous coworker. The server hosting the application must be shut down and therefore I'm migrating the application to a new server.

The old server is running IIS6, but the the new server is running IIS7.5. When I try to open the site on the new server, I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. The YSOD does not provide much info on what's going wrong (see below).

[image: Exception shown on load]

When I run the application locally in Visual Studio it works like a charm. Do any of you have a clue to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest that you take a clean web.config from the Umbraco 4.7.1 archive and try that first. You can download v4.7.1 from this unofficial archive http://code.leekelleher.com/umbraco/archive/

Merge your customisations into the web.config e.g. connection string and give that a go as I suspect your web.config is not migrated to IIS7.

I wrote a blog post a few years ago about migrating web.config files from IIS6 > IIS7 which may be of use if the above advice doesn't help:

http://www.prolificnotion.co.uk/use-appcmd-to-migrate-web-config-from-iis6-to-iis7/

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In order to satisfy my own curiosity and for the benefit of others with similar problems,  which route did you take to resolve? Merging your customizations into a clean web.config or migrating your existing one?

Comment: I merged my own into a clean web.config. That seemed as the best route, because I knew that the web.config was working before i added my own stuff. So adding one line at a time gave me the possibility to identify which line (if any) was breaking the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your application pool is running the correct version of the .Net Framework? Also check the pipeline mode you are running - mine run in Integrated mode not Classic.

In the `<system.webServer>` node of your web.config locate the `<modules>` node and ensure you have the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute set to true as that has caught me out a few times. It should look something like this:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

I suspect the latter advice is the one that will do it for you.

Simon

Comment: Hi Simon,
I already tried to play around with the application pool settings and the RAMMFAR setting, but I get the same error regardsless of RAMMFAR being true or false. The same goes for the pipeline mode. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean? Restarting IIS completely?

Comment: Yes, sometimes Umbraco has some weirdness that a restart of IIS shakes out.

Comment: Just restarted the server, but the same error occurs. Do you have any other ideas? It _must_ be some server setting that is wrong, since the application is running fine on the old server.

Answer (score 0):

Just riffing on some of @Pronotion's suggestions ... I have occasionally had issues installing apps on new server instances and have had to reinstall IIS. It's a single command line: `aspnet_regiis -i`

Also from your screenshot, it looks like you are running a .Net 4 app pool. Umbraco 4.7.1 should be running under .Net 2 Classic app pool as far as I remember.

Comment: I think you might be right since the release page for 4.7.1 does not mention .Net Version http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/471/ArchivedRelease/ yet 4.7.1.1 does then go on to say .Net 4 is a requirement http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/4711/

Comment: I'd be interested to see. According to the details here http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/upgrading-an-umbraco-installation 4.7.1 requires .Net 4, but I was convinced it ran in a lower app pool.

Comment: Yes it does state on that page "Umbraco versions 4.7.0 and above all require ASP.NET 4.0, but versions prior to this come with support for either ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.0"